# Clone button on Report not displaying

Tags: reporting, button, clone

For some time now the clone button on the Report object has been missing in both lightning and classic.

I'm trying to identify why and get it back up there since this button makes our lives so much easier.

Does anybody have a similar issue?
Anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Is Report object a custom object in your org?

Comment: @AyubAnsari no. It's the standard reporting tool that comes with Salesforce and that works with Dashboard.

Comment: I don't think there is any clone button on any report. Although there is "Save As" button which works as clone.

Answer (score 0):

There is no clone button in SF Reports. As Ayub pointed out, the next best thing would be to use the "Save As" button.